# Connection with Redis is not synchronous?

Tags: flask, redis

I have a Flask route that returns deterministic responses when run with a single thread (either in development mode or in production with `gunicorn -w 1`, but behaves non-deterministically when run with more gunicorn workers e.g. `gunicorn -w 3`.

After calling e.g. `GET /do_something/hello` once and getting a 200, when I call `GET /do_something/hello` again I sometimes get a 200, while at other times I get a 500. When I get a 200 again, after trying for a few times it seems to stabilise at giving me a 500.

Recording whether 'foo' has been seen is done using Redis.

I thought Redis was single-threaded and synchronous. How can I fix this?

```
# I'm using redis-py, redis is initialised with StrictRedis()
@flask_app.route('/do_something/<string:foo>')
def do_something(foo: str):
  seen = pickle.loads(redis.get('seen'))
  if foo in seen:
    return 'Foo already seen', 500
  try:
    seen.append(foo)
    redis.put('seen', pickle.dumps(seen))
    // Do something
    return 'Done'
  except ValueError:
    return 'Error during processing!', 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct Redis is single threaded.

The issue may be a race condition with a second client read prior to your write. If the key you are writing back becomes large the latency would increase the likelihood of this being observed.

Not certain of the full use case but adding the value as a member in a set would allow you to inspect the return value (0 when the member exists, 1 if new). Any client connecting after this write would see the presence of that member in the set. `SMEMBERS` could always be used after to inspect the members of the set if you need to work with them as well.

```
def do_something(foo: str):
  try:
    seen = redis.sadd('seen', foo)
  except redis.RedisError:
    return 'Error during processing!', 500

  if seen == 0:
    return 'Foo already seen', 500
  else:
    // Do something
    return 'Done'
```